# linear function in c#

Tags: c#, linear-algebra

My C# Program receives Values from 4.95 to 3.5. Each stands for a linear linked row of other values (water in liter, see picture). How can I program the linear function and link the values with each other? Do I need a matrix like this: `var m = Matrix.Create(4, 4, new double[]`?

[image: Values****]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a moment and read [ask]. As it is the question is too broad. Try to solve this yourself and when you run into a problem, add your code as [mcve] and explain in detail what is not working as you intend.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? do you need an equation to convert Volt to liter?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Yes so when there is a voltage of 3.1 3.1 is added to the equation

Comment: @Esko sorry for the broad question. So then is my question how do you add an linear equation to the program? I didnt found any nice examples so far.

Comment: You can just create something like `var matrix = new double[28, 2];` Over here 28 is the nr of rows from your excel sheet and 2 is the nr of columns. You can adapt this to your needs.
In order to access the data for any calculations you might need to do you can use a double loop and the indexes, something like :
`for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
     for (j = 0 < j < 2; j++)
     {
         do something with matrix [i, j]
     }`

Comment: The first element of Liter water column will be matrix [0, 0] while the first element of Voltage column will be matrix [0, 1], 2nd element of Liter water is matrix[1. 0] and 2nd element of Voltage column is matrix [1, 1] and so on